# Is it ok to use a different oil in my LPG Suzuki?

Tags: oil, suzuki, lpg

I have a Suzuki Liana 2002 with LPG system (lovato).
I use this lubricant (which I was told to by the guy who installed my system)

[this is what I use](http://www.ebay.de/itm/2x-LPG-Autogas-Prins-VSI-Valve-Care-L2-Ventilschutz-0-5-Ltr/301484720130?_trksid=p5411.c100167.m2940&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140131123730%26meid%3Dbb8fa9fd58b24d26a40ed0f5b86f27bd%26pid%3D100167%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D10%26sd%3D301484718320)

Unfortunately it costs a lot. I saw there was another one I wanted to use if I can use the other one which is cheaper and it will do the same job perhaps?

[the other one I wish to know if I can use](http://www.ebay.de/itm/2-x-FLASH-LUBE-0-5-L-VALVE-CARE-FLUID-FUR-PRINS-SYSTEME-/161299215669?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item258e2eb535)

Is there any 5 Liter refill I can use to refill my original one?